# Series from $n=0$ to $\infty$ of $cos(x)^n$ converges for what values of x?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

By the root test, I have got to this stage:

$\limsup \cos(x) < 1$ (for convergence)

I am stuck on showing for what values of x this would converge.

I know that lim sup is the maximum of accumulation points but unsure on how to proceed from there.

Comment: For values of $x$ not divisible by $\pi$.

Comment: Is this because for cos(npi) you get the values 1,-1 which do not converge by root or ratio test?

Comment: Yes. – – – – – –

Comment: What do you mean by $\limsup \cos(x)$ ? If $x$ is fixed, then $cos(x)$ is just a specific number, you don't need to take $\limsup$ of just a single number. In the title, do you mean $cos((x)^n)$ or $(cos(x))^n$ (the latter case would be easy, and the former may be more difficult unless $|x|<1$ ) ?

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_ny^n$ converges iff $|y|<1.$ So with $y=\cos x$ we have convergence iff $|\cos x|<1.$

For real $x$ we have $|\cos x|=1 \iff x/\pi\in \mathbb Z,$ and also $|\cos x|<1\iff  x/\pi\not \in \mathbb Z.$ So for real $x$ we have convergence iff $x/\pi \not \in \mathbb Z.$